# Trying to run some cocos2D demos in Xcode 5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I just downloaded cocos2D and was following their tutorials. Unfortunately I got stuck on the first one. The tutorial is located at http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:lesson_1._install_test and I'm stuck on step 2: running the tests.

I simply want to run their demos like they say *"If you are using Xcode 4 you have to select a scheme, which specifies which targets to build, what build configuration to use, which debugger to use, and which executable to launch. Just Option + Click the Run button and select your scheme from the drop down list – for example, “SpriteTest” or “ParticleTest”."*

Below is a screenshot of what happens when I follow their directions in Xcode 5. I don't see the option to select "SpriteTest" as a scheme.

[image]

Additionally, if I just choose to build and run on cocos2d, then I get an error as below

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The error isn't cryptic in the slightest.  You're missing a file.

Comment: seems strange since i simply downloaded it off the website and didn't fuss with it at all...

Comment: What's strange is that you're asking Stack Overflow about a missing file from a project you downloaded elsewhere.  Why don't you ask those people?

Comment: well you clearly didn't read my whole question. Mainly my question was about why "SpriteTest" or "ParticleTest" isn't showing up as a scheme, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be cocos2d 3.0. Am I correct?
If you downloaded the code directly from GitHub and didn't install it using the installer, you need to run a

```
git submodule update --init
```

In order to install the dependencies.

Also note, that cocos2d 3.0 is work in progress and the documentation on www.cocos2d-iphone.org currently doesn't apply to that release.

Comment: Thanks! Would you recommend installing an older version for now to learn?

Comment: If you have never used cocos2d, I would suggest starting with Kobold2D (basically cocos2d 2.x with ARC) since there is no learning material around for 3.0, yet.

You can check our tutorials out: https://www.makegameswith.us/tutorials/learn/

We will also provide a transition guide to 3.0 once there is a stable release.